# Switch from Windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, windows, windows-7, overheating

My current PC is running on Intel Core 2 Duo processor 2.80GHz with 2GB RAM. I run Windows 7 32-bit on this configuration, but the PC shuts down sometimes due to over heating. Also, the CPU is always running on more than 50% capacity. Will switching to Ubuntu address these problems? Can i get a faster OS with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

No and Yes. If your PC overheats, the first thing you need do is to clean the Heat Sink. Then check the Drivers. If you have Nvidia GFX card Ubuntu will run fine.

You can download an ISO, Burn that to a DVD or install that into a Pen Drive, and then Boot into a Live Session. Make a through test how your system performs, if everything goes well, then Install it either along side Windows or Overwrite Windows.

Check this Link - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest